# How can I correct the settling time when implementing a pre-filter (reference filtering)?

Tags: filter-design, control-systems, feedback, pid

I have designed a controller for the speed of a motor, I calculated that for a settling time $0.1 \; s$, it works when I test it without pre-filtering. However, I need $0$ overshoot, so I implemented a pre-filter. But this filter makes my settling time larger (like $1\; s$).

I wish to know if there is anyway to implement a pre-filter without affecting my settling time that much, or not affecting it at all.

Comment: What do you mean by prefilter. You mean a filter between the reference and the error calculation?

Comment: Exactly! That´s what i mean!